# MYSQL cantidad de columnas variables

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en mysql que me muestre la siguiente información.

Tengo una tabla que registra la hora de ingreso trabajadores, quisiera sacar a través de un filtro de fechas, por ejemplo del 2018-10-15 al 2018-10-31, la relación del horario de ingreso.

```js
SELECT
r1.id_trab,
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '1'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '2'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia2',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '3'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia3',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '4'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia4',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '5'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia5',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '6'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia6',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '7'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia7',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '8'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia8',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '9'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia9',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '10'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia10',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '11'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia11',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '12'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia12',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '13'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia13',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '13'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia12',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '14'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia14',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '15'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia15',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '16'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia16',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '17'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia17',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '18'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia18',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '19'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia19',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '20'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia20',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '21'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia21',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '22'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia22',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '23'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia23',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '24'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia24',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '25'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia25',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '26'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia26',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '27'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia27',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '28'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia28',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '29'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia29',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '30'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia30',
  MAX(CASE WHEN r.dia = '31'
    THEN r1.hor_ent ELSE 0 END) AS 'hor_ent_dia31'
FROM reloj r1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT DAY(fecha) AS dia,
    MONTH(fecha) AS mes FROM reloj r WHERE r.fecha BETWEEN '2019-05-15'
    AND '2019-05-30'
    GROUP BY DAY(fecha)) AS r
ON DAY(r1.fecha) = r.dia
WHERE r1.fecha BETWEEN '2019-05-15'
AND '2019-05-30'
GROUP BY r1.id_trab;
```

[image: este es el resultado de mi query, que esta bien hasta el momento]

La consulta hasta el momento me muestra la información del mes completo, **me gustaría mejorarlo** dándole la opción de escoger el rango de fechas y que solo **me muestre LOS DÍAS que se encuentren ese ese rango y ya no todo el mes**, ya que ahora si no esta dentro del rango, me muestra TODOS LOS DÍAS con datos vacíos. Que si escojo un rango de 10 días, me muestre solo 10 COLUMNAS, si pido un rango de 27 días, me muestre 27 columnas y de esa forma.

Desde agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar. adjunto la base de datos y tablas que ayuden a realizar el ejercicio.

[BASE DE DATOS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iD0yfGn71KifI8_ToSZmS1mZ-17j8TBc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto no está fácil, pero se puede hacer con un `statement`

Empecemos con lo básico. Si tú pones

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
    'MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=',
     dia,
     ' THEN hor_ent ',
     ' ELSE 0 END) ',
     ' AS hor_ent_dia',
     dia
    )
 )
FROM 
(SELECT DAY(fecha) AS dia FROM reloj 
 WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-05-15' AND '2019-05-30' GROUP BY DAY(fecha)
) r;
```

El resultado es un texto que dice:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=15 THEN hor_ent  ELSE 0 END)  AS hor_ent_dia15,MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=23 THEN hor_ent  ELSE 0 END)  AS hor_ent_dia23,MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=24 THEN hor_ent  ELSE 0 END)  AS hor_ent_dia24,MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=25 THEN hor_ent  ELSE 0 END)  AS hor_ent_dia25,MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=26 THEN hor_ent  ELSE 0 END)  AS hor_ent_dia26
```

de manera que si pudieras crear una query con ese texto en medio, habrías solucionado el problema.

Ahora bien, no es llegar y meter un texto arbitrario como parte de una query. Para eso existen los statements. Piensa que puedes hacer:

```
SET @campos = ' id_trab, fecha ';
SET @consulta = CONCAT('SELECT ',@campos,' FROM reloj');
PREPARE stmt FROM @consulta;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Y con eso ejecutaste un string como si fuera una query.

Juntando lo de arriba con lo anterior, podemos armar la query final como:

```
SET @campos = NULL;
SET @consulta = NULL;

SELECT (@campos := GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
    'MAX(CASE WHEN DAY(fecha)=',
     dia,
     ' THEN hor_ent ',
     ' ELSE 0 END) ',
     ' AS hor_ent_dia',
     dia
    )
 ))
FROM 
(SELECT DAY(fecha) AS dia FROM reloj 
 WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-05-15' AND '2019-05-30' GROUP BY DAY(fecha)
) r;
SET @consulta = CONCAT('SELECT  id_trab, ', @campos, ' 
                   FROM reloj
                   WHERE fecha BETWEEN ''2019-05-15'' AND ''2019-05-30'' GROUP BY id_trab');
PREPARE stmt FROM @consulta;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Y eso te entregaría el resultado final mostrando sólo las columnas que tienen datos.